# How does これ以上する work in this particular context?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-choice

I've already learned how to use これ以上 when it means "beyond this" or further than this". But I'm confused as what it means in this particular context I came across.

I've been reading a sports manga. For context a girl cooks lunch for her friend once to motivate him to attend practice. The friend then adds another request on top of that, being for her buy him tea. The girl then says this.

これ以上するなら全国行かないと許しませんから...

What confuses me here is whether これ以上する suggests that she'll do this more in the future (cooking lunch and buying tea) OR she's only saying she'll do it this time without promising to do it more in the future (the original promise was only cooking lunch once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you might be able to construct a context where the former meaning (that she'll do this more in the future) made sense, the latter (that she'll do this now) is much more natural given the context you provided.

Translating very literally, the line comes out to:

> If I'm going to do any more than this I won't forgive you unless you* make it to nationals

In more natural English, this might look something like:

> If I'm gonna do all this you'd* better make it to nationals

Ultimately though the point she's trying to make is just that if she's going to go through all this trouble, she wants him to make it to nationals.

Note that if they're both on the same team/in the same sports club, the implied subject that I wrote as `you` could very easily be a `we`. Also, if you're wondering where "nationals" came from: `全国` here is an abbreviation for the `全国大会` in whatever sport they're playing, in the same way we say `nationals` for `national championships` in English.